# what gauge wire do i need to run for a sub panel that's like 4' away

Tags: basement

I am installing a 100 amp  sub panel for my basement. I am just trying to get the correct wire so I pass the inspection for the basement. I am trying to do all the work myself and i don' know what wire i will need for the Georgia building code.

Comment: what kind of searching online and on this site have you done so far?

Comment: What size breaker in the main panel is going to power the sub panel?  That breaker will determine the size of wire you need, not the size of the sub panel  A 100 amp sub panel only means the feeder breaker is 100 amps or less.  If you use a 30 amp breaker then need only 10 gauge, a 100amp around 2 gauge copper(depending on wire type).  After you do a load calculation to see how much you can use.

Answer (score 2):

See NEC table 310.15(B)(16).

Assuming you're not using NM* or UF cable, you can use the 75C column.

That means #1 aluminum or #3 copper will suffice.

* Because of NEC 334.80.